# How do I have something in a CASE statement without including it in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been working on a query to gather some information and I'm getting a little bit stuck.

In my query, I have a CASE statement to look at the Unit of Measure, and do a calculation dependent on whether or not the unit is one or the other.

My problem is that when I am looking at a particular record, it is showing as 2 records when I would like it to just show as 1, but add up the figures from both.

Unfortunately the reason why the 2 records show is because I am forced to have a group by on the unit, and as they are different they split over 2 lines.

My query is this:

```
Select
C.CaseID,
DATEPART(Year,C.ResolvedDate) 'Year',
DATENAME(Month,C.ResolvedDate) 'Month',
CASE 
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID IN ('FGBCTFLR','FGBCTFLD','FGBCTLIS','FGBCTSAM','FGBCTSEC') THEN 'ManufacturedCeramics'
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID = 'FGBCTGLS' THEN 'ManufacturedGlass'
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID IN ('FGFACTAG','FGFACTFLD','FGFACTFLR','FGFACTLIS','FGTOOLS') THEN 'Factored' 
End as 'Category',
COALESCE(CASE WHEN D.UnitID = 'BOX' THEN
    SUM(D.QtyAffected * I.BCT_Product_Qty / (1 / NULLIF((convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Width) / 1000 * convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Height) / 1000),0)))
ELSE
    SUM(D.QtyAffected / (1 / NULLIF((convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Width) / 1000 * convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Height) / 1000),0)))
End,0) as 'M2 Affected',
C.CostReplacementTile + C.CostRedelivery + C.CostCredit + C.CostRefixing + C.CostVoucher 'Cost'

From BCTComplaintRegister C

Left Join BCTComplaintProductRegister D
On D.CaseID = C.CaseID

Left Join InventTable I
On I.ItemID = D.ItemID

Left Join BCTTileSize T
On T.TileSizeID = I.BCTTileSize

Where 
DATEDIFF(M,C.ResolvedDate,GETDATE()) <= 12
And C.QAOutcome IN (1,2,5)
And C.Status = '4'
AND C.CaseID = 'CE20300'

Group By
    DATEPART(Year,C.ResolvedDate),
    DATENAME(Month,C.ResolvedDate),
    I.ItemGroupID,
    C.CaseID,
    C.CostReplacementTile,
    c.costredelivery,
c.costcredit,
c.costrefixing,
c.costvoucher,
d.unitid

Order By
    C.CaseId
```

The results are the following:

```
CaseID: CE20300, CE20300   <br>
Year: 2016, 2016<br>
Month: April, April<br>
Category: ManCer, ManCer<br>
M2 Affected: 23.56, 0.81
Cost: 2292, 2292
```

(sorry not sure how to do a table on here).
I need this to show as one line but with the M2 as a total value for both, the cost should stay the same.

How can I achieve this?

Sorry if anything is unclear.

Comment: That's a case expression (returns a value), not a case statement.

Comment: ok. sorry......

Comment: I assume you want to group by the _result_ of the case expression.  You either have to include the entire CASE statement in the GROUP BY or use a subquery to map the categories and group in the outer query.

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct. When trying to add the entire case statement, I get the error Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a group by clause.

Comment: @Barnold When you added the Category case?  You don;t need to add the M2 Affected case.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, I'm not having problems with the ItemGroupID case, just the M2Affected case.

Comment: @jarlh Sadly, "case statement" is "By Design" according to [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1546816/remove-case-statement-from-transact-sql-documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn the COALESCE expression into a subquery that is grouped on unitid?

```
Select
C.CaseID,
DATEPART(Year,C.ResolvedDate) 'Year',
DATENAME(Month,C.ResolvedDate) 'Month',
CASE 
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID IN ('FGBCTFLR','FGBCTFLD','FGBCTLIS','FGBCTSAM','FGBCTSEC') THEN 'ManufacturedCeramics'
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID = 'FGBCTGLS' THEN 'ManufacturedGlass'
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID IN ('FGFACTAG','FGFACTFLD','FGFACTFLR','FGFACTLIS','FGTOOLS') THEN 'Factored' 
End as 'Category',
sum(D.M2Affected) as 'M2 Affected',
C.CostReplacementTile + C.CostRedelivery + C.CostCredit + C.CostRefixing + C.CostVoucher 'Cost'

From BCTComplaintRegister C

Left Join (select 
COALESCE(CaseID, CASE WHEN D.UnitID = 'BOX' THEN
    SUM(D.QtyAffected * I.BCT_Product_Qty / (1 / NULLIF((convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Width) / 1000 * convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Height) / 1000),0)))
ELSE
    SUM(D.QtyAffected / (1 / NULLIF((convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Width) / 1000 * convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Height) / 1000),0)))
End,0) as M2Affected
from BCTComplaintProductRegister group by unitid) D
On D.CaseID = C.CaseID

Left Join InventTable I
On I.ItemID = D.ItemID

Left Join BCTTileSize T
On T.TileSizeID = I.BCTTileSize

Where 
DATEDIFF(M,C.ResolvedDate,GETDATE()) <= 12
And C.QAOutcome IN (1,2,5)
And C.Status = '4'
AND C.CaseID = 'CE20300'

Group By
    DATEPART(Year,C.ResolvedDate),
    DATENAME(Month,C.ResolvedDate),
    I.ItemGroupID,
    C.CaseID,
    C.CostReplacementTile,
    c.costredelivery,
c.costcredit,
c.costrefixing,
c.costvoucher

Order By
    C.CaseId;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It seems to sort of work. i.e. it is giving me the results as expected now, but still duplicating the line (despite showing correct figures)

Comment: Can you use sum(D.M2Affected) as 'M2 Affected'?

Comment: It then shows 2 lines but one has the M2 affected doubled.

Comment: It's almost like it's a problem with the join. If I just put the nested query into it's own query, it returns 1 row with the correct figures. It's as soon as I put it in the nested query then it shows 2 rows.

Comment: hmmm, what are the results of the "select coalesce ... " subquery?

Comment: I wonder if you need to group the subquery by both caseID and unitID, and then join the subquery on both caseID and unitID?

Comment: If I just run the nested query, I get this back: CaseID - CE20300, M2Affected 24.38. Just one row - which is what I am wanting, but when it gets put into the full query it doubles up. (i.e. doubles up as in 2 rows appear with the exact same data)

Comment: I bet you need to group by both CaseID and unitID in the subquery. Sorry about that!

Comment: This is what I already have done so I'm not too sure that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split up the query to calculate M2 Affected separately.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp1
FROM
(
Select
C.CaseID,
DATEPART(Year,C.ResolvedDate) 'Year',
DATENAME(Month,C.ResolvedDate) 'Month',
CASE 
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID IN ('FGBCTFLR','FGBCTFLD','FGBCTLIS','FGBCTSAM','FGBCTSEC') THEN 'ManufacturedCeramics'
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID = 'FGBCTGLS' THEN 'ManufacturedGlass'
    WHEN
        I.ItemGroupID IN ('FGFACTAG','FGFACTFLD','FGFACTFLR','FGFACTLIS','FGTOOLS') THEN 'Factored' 
End as 'Category',

C.CostReplacementTile + C.CostRedelivery + C.CostCredit + C.CostRefixing + C.CostVoucher 'Cost'

From BCTComplaintRegister C

Left Join BCTComplaintProductRegister D
On D.CaseID = C.CaseID

Left Join InventTable I
On I.ItemID = D.ItemID

Left Join BCTTileSize T
On T.TileSizeID = I.BCTTileSize

Where 
DATEDIFF(M,C.ResolvedDate,GETDATE()) <= 12
And C.QAOutcome IN (1,2,5)
And C.Status = '4'
AND C.CaseID = 'CE20300'

Group By
    DATEPART(Year,C.ResolvedDate),
    DATENAME(Month,C.ResolvedDate),
    I.ItemGroupID,
    C.CaseID,
    C.CostReplacementTile,
    c.costredelivery,
c.costcredit,
c.costrefixing,
c.costvoucher,
d.unitid
) P

SELECT 
    COALESCE(CASE WHEN D.UnitID = 'BOX' THEN
        SUM(D.QtyAffected * I.BCT_Product_Qty / (1 / NULLIF((convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Width) / 1000 * convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Height) / 1000),0)))
    ELSE
        SUM(D.QtyAffected / (1 / NULLIF((convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Width) / 1000 * convert(decimal(18,3),I.BCT_Product_Height) / 1000),0)))
    End,0) as 'M2 Affected'
INTO #temp2
FROM BCTComplaintProductRegister D
Left Join InventTable I
On I.ItemID = D.ItemID
Group By
    D.unitid

SELECT 
T1.CaseID,
Year,
Month, 
Category, 
Cost, 
SUM(T2.[M2 Affected]) AS [M2 Affected]

FROM #temp1 T1 
INNER JOIN #temp2 T2
ON T1.CaseID = T2.CaseID

Group By
    T1.CaseID,
    Year,
    Month, 
    Category, 
    Cost

Order By
    C.CaseId
```

The last 2 select queries can be merged if it works.